# Horizontal disabled scrollbar in Facebook Canvas with Firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox, iframe

I have disabled horizontal scrollbar in my Facebook App (FF9).

I've read every post here or in blogs regarding problems like this one. So far I've used `setAutoGrow` and applied `overflow: hidden` on `body` and `html`.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Please keep the ranting to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js. This issue has been reported numerous times as a bug but never confirmed by Facebook (see [this bug report](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/199425823482620/?browse=search_4ef0e8ec0f8074996313980)).

This code also takes care of `all.js` mishandling secure connection.

Note that the code requires http://jquery.com/ to work.

**Regarding the scrollbar**

The trick is to load `all.js` asynchronously only after DOM has been fully loaded. Then seek `fbAsyncInit` callback and continue with `setAutoGrow`.

You've also mentioned the fixed width (520px) and `overflow(-x): hidden`. This is a good idea, though, not necessary. Note that if you decide to go this way, apply fix width on `body` element and not some internal wrapping element.

See the following code and comments enclosed.

```
$(function(){
    window.fbAsyncInit  = function()
    {
        // fixes the HTTPS issue
        // _https: (window.name.indexOf('_fb_https') > -1),
        // @version /*1328456404,169895806,JIT Construction: v505175,en_US*/
        FB._https           = true;

        // fix for all.js
        // the following line enforces using non-secure URL (why Facebook?)
        // FB.getDomain((c?'https_':'')+'staticfb',true)
        // @version /*1328456404,169895806,JIT Construction: v505175,en_US*/

        FB._domain.api      = 'https://api-read.facebook.com/';
        FB._domain.cdn      = 'https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/';
        FB._domain.staticfb = 'https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/';
        FB._domain.www      = 'https://www.facebook.com/';
        FB._domain.m        = 'https://m.facebook.com/';

        FB.init({appId: [app id], channelUrl: '[domain]/channel.php', status: true, cookie: true, oauth: true, xfbml: true});

        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(91);
        // it is good idea to ensure that page will always open top-most view when navigated internally
        FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0,0);
    };

    // Load the SDK Asynchronously after the DOM is loaded
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";

        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
});
```